# How to check for a folder in 2 machines using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am working on a shell script which I need to run on `machineX`. It will check for a certain folder which is in this format `YYYYMMDD` inside this folder `MAPPED_LOCATION` in other two machines - `machineP` and `machineQ`. So the path will be like this in both `machineP` and `machineQ`-

```
/bat/testdata/t1_snapshot/20140311
```

And inside the above folder path, there will be some files inside in it. Below is my shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly MACHINES=(machineP machineQ)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/testdata/t1_snapshot
readonly FILE_TIMESTAMP=20140311

# old code which I was using to get the latest folder inside each machine (P and Q)
dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${MACHINES[0]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${MACHINES[1]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

dir3=$MAPPED_LOCATION/$FILE_TIMESTAMP # /bat/testdata/t1_snapshot/20140311

echo $dir1
echo $dir2
echo $dir3

if dir3 path exists in both the machines (P and Q) and number of files is greater than zero in each machine
then

    # then do something here
    echo "Hello World"

else

    # log an error - folder is missing or number of files is zero in which servers or both servers

fi
```

Noow what I am supposed to do is - If this path exists `/bat/testdata/t1_snapshot/20140311` in both of the machines and number of files are greater than zero in both of the machines, then do somethting. Else if the folder is missing in any of the servers or number of files is zero in any of ther servers, I will exit out of the shell script with non zero status and a message with an actual error.

How can I do this in shell script?

**Update:-**

```
for machine in $MACHINES; do
   dircheck=($(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${machine} [[ ! -d "$dir3" ]] \&\& exit 1 \; ls -t1 "$dir3"))

   #On the ssh command, we exit 1 if the folder doesn't exist. We check the return code with `$?`
   if [[ $? != 0 ]] ;then
       echo "Folder doesn't exist on $machine"; 
       exit 1
   fi

   # check number of files retrieved
   if [[ "${dircheck[@]}" = 0 ]] ;then
       echo "0 Files on server $machine"; 
       exit 1
   fi
  #all good for $machine here
done

echo "Everything is Correct"
```

If I am adding a new empty folder `20140411` inside `machineP` and then execute the above script, it always prints out -

```
echo "Everything is Correct"
```

Infact, I didn't added any folder in `machineQ`. Not sure what is the  problem?

**Another Update-**

I have created an empty  folder `20140411` in `machineP` only. And then I ran the script in debug mode -

```
david@machineX:~$ ./test_file_check_1.sh
+ FILERS_LOCATION=(machineP machineQ)
+ readonly FILERS_LOCATION
+ readonly MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot
+ MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot
+ readonly FILE_TIMESTAMP=20140411
+ FILE_TIMESTAMP=20140411
+ dir3=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140411
+ echo /bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140411
/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140411
+ for machine in '$FILERS_LOCATION'
+ dircheck=($(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${machine} [[ ! -d "$dir3" ]] \&\& exit 1 \; ls -t1 "$dir3"))
++ ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' david@machineP '[[' '!' -d /bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140411 ']]' '&&' exit 1 ';' ls -t1 /bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot/20140411
+ [[ 0 != 0 ]]
+ [[ '' = 0 ]]
+ echo 'Everything is Correct'
Everything is Correct
```

Comment: One way would be to use find with a pipe to wc -l to count the files in the directory and compare that. Or maybe you want to use rsync --dry-run to see what the diff between the two directories is and act upon that.

Comment: @user2809564 The code checking if the file exist is working. (If I try on my server and the folder doesn't exist, it exits with the good error). Are you sure machineP was in the MACHINES ? run the script in debug. Replace `#!/bin/bash` by `#!/bin/bash -x` and add the output to the post

Comment: @naab: I just updated the question for you with details in debug mode.

Comment: It works fine if the folder doesn't exist on one servers try creating an empty folder on one servers and then run it. I can see the error if the folders are not there as well. But after creating a folder on one machine and then I am running it. I always see the above issue.

Comment: There are no quotes around that and this is what I am using `for machine in $FILERS_LOCATION; do`. See your answer as well. I just used whatever you  provided me.

Comment: In fact the fix is like this - `for machine in "${FILERS_LOCATION[@]}"; do`. This works fine but this doesn't check zero files case as I have zero files in machineP folder.

Comment: @user2809564 Updated. Should now all work like intended. Sorry for not posting correct code in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is, ls the remote directory (remove the `-d` flag to `ls` (which lists only folders), and the `head -n1` command as it only prints the first file) and retrieve the data in an array variable.

I also added a check for directory existance `[[ -d "$dir3" ]]` before executing the `ls`  and escaped the && to not be interpreted on the current bash script.

```
[[ -d "$dir3" ]] \&\& ls -t1 "$dir3"
```

To define a bash array, add extra `( )` arround the command., then compare the array size.

```
dir3="$MAPPED_LOCATION/$FILE_TIMESTAMP" # /bat/testdata/t1_snapshot/20140311

for machine in ${MACHINES[*]}; do
   dir3check=($(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${machine} [[ -d "$dir3" ]] \&\& ls -t1 "$dir3"))

   if [[ "${#dir3check[@]}" -gt 0 ]] ;then
       # then do something here
       echo "Hello World"
   else
       # log an error - folder is missing or number of files is zero in server $machine
   fi
done
```

UPDATE:

```
for machine in ${MACHINES[*]}; do
   dircheck=($(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${machine} [[ ! -d "$dir3" ]] \&\& exit 1 \; ls -t1 "$dir3"))

   #On the ssh command, we exit 1 if the folder doesn't exist. We check the return code with `$?`
   if [[ $? != 0 ]] ;then
       echo "Folder doesn't exist on $machine"; 
       exit 1
   fi

   # check number of files retrieved
   if [[ "${#dircheck[@]}" = 0 ]] ;then
       echo "0 Files on server $machine"; 
       exit 1
   fi
  #all good for $machine here
done
#all good for all machines here
```

Comment: Thanks. If the folder doesn't exist, then `dir3check` line gives an error saying No such file or directory?

Comment: @AKIWEB If the folder doesn't exist, `dir3check` will be an empty array and go in the else statement on the array size check

Comment: @naab: Thanks. Is there any way I can do this without for loops? Basically I can use  machine Array index 0 and 1 to do the check and get the specific error which has happened? I have updated the question with my example.

Comment: @user2809564 Yes you can, but it's ugly. And what if you add another server some day ? you have to change 10-20 lines of code and won't be sure if it will work as intended while I need to change 1 and i'm sure it will work.

Comment: @naab: Sure naab, makes sense but in my example it is always going to be two servers always so I was trying to make it simple. Anyways, I just tried your example and I got this error `syntax error near unexpected token `done'` Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @naab: Thanks naab that issue got fixed. I have noticed pretty weird thing just now. If I add a new empty folder `20140411` only on one machine, let's say `machineP` and then execute your scripts. It doesn't give me error as zero files in that folder for that `machneP` and also. Any thoughts?

Comment: @naab: Updated the question with details.